# kafka connect cassandra - connection refused

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to connect kafka with cassandra sink, it seems like there is a connection issue though. 
I first got this report:

```
Validating connector properties before posting
Connector properties valid. Creating connector cassandra-sink-orders
java.net.ConnectException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt (**Connection refused**)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest$$anonfun$8.apply(Http.scala:426)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest$$anonfun$8.apply(Http.scala:424)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.exec(Http.scala:347)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.execute(Http.scala:322)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.asString(Http.scala:537)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.ScalajHttpClient$.request(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:39)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi.com$datamountaineer$connect$tools$RestKafkaConnectApi$$req(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:129)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi$$anonfun$addConnector$1.apply(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:167)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi$$anonfun$addConnector$1.apply(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:168)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi.addConnector(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:167)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.ExecuteCommand$.apply(Cli.scala:55)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.Cli$.main(Cli.scala:167)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.Cli.main(Cli.scala)
```

I looked it up and changed some settings I got recommended:

in cassandra.yaml: `now (before)`

```
start_rpc: true (false)
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 (localhost)
broadcast_rpc_address: 255.255.255.255 (commented out)
```

and chmod of var/lib/cassandra and var/log/cassandra to 777 to have all permissions.

Now I m getting another issue report:

```
Validating connector properties before posting
Connector properties valid. Creating connector cassandra-sink-orders
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: **Read timed out**
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:192)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:192)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.exec(Http.scala:351)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.execute(Http.scala:322)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.asString(Http.scala:537)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.ScalajHttpClient$.request(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:39)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi.com$datamountaineer$connect$tools$RestKafkaConnectApi$$req(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:129)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi$$anonfun$addConnector$1.apply(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:167)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi$$anonfun$addConnector$1.apply(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:168)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.RestKafkaConnectApi.addConnector(RestKafkaConnectApi.scala:167)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.ExecuteCommand$.apply(Cli.scala:55)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.Cli$.main(Cli.scala:167)
at com.datamountaineer.connect.tools.Cli.main(Cli.scala)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.exec(Http.scala:349)
... 11 more
```

Hope there is anyone out there who can help out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is cassandra running (is the process up?)? have you looked at the cassandra logs? have you tried to connect via cqlsh (http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html)?